# Entity Framework 5 Linq Insert Query: Operation is invalid

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, webforms

I have an error when trying to execute a simple linq insert query.

> Exception: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

Here is my linq query:

```
private void addEntry(string hqname, string hqaddress, string hqcity,
                      int hqzip, string hqstate, string hqcountry)
{
    using (var db = new dbcontext())
    {
        try
        {
            var dbObj = new dbObj();
            dbObj.HQName = hqname;
            dbObj.HQAddress = hqaddress;
            dbObj.HQCity = hqcity;
            dbObj.HQZip = hqzip;
            dbObj.HQState = hqstate;
            dbObj.HQCountry = hqcountry;
            db.tblName.Add(dbObj);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
    }
}
```

and here's where I call this method:

```
addCompanyHeadquarters(tbCompanyName.Text, addressInput.HQAddress, addressInput.HQCity, Convert.ToInt32(addressInput.HQZip), addressInput.HQState, "United States");
```

Stack Trace:

> [InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.]
>          addCompanyHeadquarters(String hqname, String hqaddress, String hqcity, Int32 hqzip, String hqstate, String hqcountry) in 
>          Button3_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in 
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9692746
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +108
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +12
>          System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
>          System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
>          System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3562

I've been trying to debug this for awhile and this error is really throwing me for a loop. I'm not sure what to look into next. Any tips to move forward is greatly appreciated. Some Info: I had to update the id database column to autoincrement and then after I changed the `edmx` file for the respective table and column `StoredGeneratedPattern: True`

**Update:** from the advice of Egor Semenenko I added changed the exception i throw to **throw;**: 
Heres my new stack trace:
**the entity type is not part of the model for the current context** 
[InvalidOperationException: The entity type tblName is not part of the model for the current context.]

```
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.UpdateEntitySetMappingsForType(Type entityType) +196
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +38
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +52
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +15
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName) +64
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity) +108
   System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity) +42
  addCompanyHeadquarters(String hqname, String hqaddress, String hqcity, Int32 hqzip, String hqstate, String hqcountry) in 
   Button3_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9692746
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +108
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +12
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3562
```

Comment: Did updating the ID to auto increment fix it?  Also, are you missing an FK relationships on this object?

Comment: updating the column to auto increment didn't fix it unfortunately and i have it set as a primary key.

Comment: The actual exception is lost on the way. I suppose you have to fix that so you'll probably make a fix and deploy it. Why don't you start first with removing the try/catch block, since is useless? Then you'll see the actual error. It might be a NULL constraint, a unique constraint violation, etc

Comment: Please show your `dbcontext` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the actual exception is? Since you are using try catch and throw your own InvalidOperationException you can not see the actual one.
Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object - just a generic error message for InvalidOperationException.

Comment: Unfortunately, the way my environment is setup I am not able to debug server side, and see the actual exception thrown. This is a webform and I just view the page inside of the browser. Because of this, this issue is harder to debug and it sucks! :(

Comment: If I comment out my exception, I am redirected to my next page as expected

Comment: I've tried running raw SQL queries also to no avail.

Comment: you can just write throw; in your catch block and you will see the actual exception

Comment: catch {
            throw;
        }

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the help. We solved the issue, inside of the ssdl file the Entity set wasn't there to map the database columns to the entity.